# how to get object content when debug in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging

how can I get object properties (now just object references - 0x484ce00) in XCode debug tool like in the Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0):

from the debugger,

> ```
>  po 0x484ce00
> ```

will print the description property of the object. The default implementation of -description is inherited from NSObject and just prints the address. So you have to override it see the object's internal state.